# jQuery DataTable - Server-side processing (Pagination and search not working)

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatable

I'm working for a restfull api that will work on datatable server-side processing, returning json file fetch to a Datatable. All the data was fetch correctly but the pagination and search is not working. I think the issues are **[draw]**, **[recordsTotal]**, and **[recordsFiltered]**. Your help saves my life. Thanks!

**Process:** HTML request -> Jquery -> datatable.ajax.get -> PHP fetch data into the server -> return json file

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example').DataTable( {
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
  "ajax": {
   "url": "api/auth",
   "type": "GET"
  },
  "columns": [
  { "data": "first_name" },
  { "data": "last_name" },
  { "data": "position" },
  { "data": "office" },
  { "data": "start_date" },
  { "data": "salary" }
  ],
   "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 1 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 2 ],
                "visible": false
            }
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'print'
        ]
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>

<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
<!-- jQuery -->
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
$serverData = $db->query('SELECT * FROM employee_tb');
foreach ($serverData as $key => $value) {
$data[] = array( 'first_name'  => $value['first_name'], 
                 'last_name'   =>  $value['last_name'],
                 'position'    =>  $value['position'],
                 'office'      =>  $value['office'],
                 'start_date'  =>  $value['start_date'],
                 'salary'      =>  $value['salary']
        );
$dataCount = count($serverData);
}
$json_data = array('draw'  => 0, 'recordsTotal' =>  $dataCount, 'recordsFiltered' =>  $dataCount, 'data' =>  $data );
echo  json_encode($json_data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending always **draw="0"** at your JSON response.

You should **capture draw parameter from request** and **send back to draw parameter** in the response.

**Your PHP file last line;**

```
$json_data = array('draw' => (isset($_REQUEST["draw"]) ? $_REQUEST["draw"] : 0), 'recordsTotal' =>  $dataCount, 'recordsFiltered' =>  $dataCount, 'data' =>  $data );
```

Your problem will be solved when you apply this.

Comment: @Dyem You should validate that it's numeric before just firing it back.