# pagination in server side datatable not working (without changing the URL)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

i have a datatable for which my jquery is as follows,

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [[10,15,20,25,-1], [10,15,20,25,'All']],
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'url2',
        dataSrc: 'data'
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'column1' },
        { data: 'column2' },
        { data: 'column3' },
        { data: 'column4' },
        { data: 'column5' },
        { data: 'column6' }
    ]
});
```

this is working properly. The only issue is although its showing pagination links, they are not clickable and all the rows are displayed in first page itself.

for eg. if there are 100 rows, the links are getting generated 1-10 but all the 100 records are showing on the first page itself.

> I've referred ,
>   https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

what am i doing wrong here?
Thank you for your suggestions

Server side code -

```
$total_records = $this->model2->getTotal();

$query['results'] = $this->model1->get_Data();


$data = array('data' => $query['results'],
                                "draw" =>  (isset($_REQUEST["draw"]) ? $_REQUEST["draw"] : 0),
                                "recordsTotal" =>  $total_records,
                                "recordsFiltered" => $total_records
                                 );
echo json_encode($data);
```

I think i know what am i doing wrong,
when i print $_GET in my php code it comes out to be empty. But it is supposed to have the limit and offset value.
How to i send limit offset in $_GET?

Comment: It seems that in the begining petition you return all the rows. Take into account that if you use this method, is the server who needs to return the rows that you are going to display and is the one that tells to the datatable plugin if it will have more pages or not. So I am considering that you have the problem in the server side

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I need to include ssp.php.class as mentioned in the tutorial, which will decide how many rows to return or do I have to apply limit offset in my query?? Can you guide me through the former case ... I am using codeigniter framework... Thank you again

Comment: Well actually it is a little bit complicated to me for guide you due to I did this using c# and not php. In the C# I had to return a JSON that contains the data, the number of total elements, the offset, etc. I don't know how it will be on PHP.

Comment: Okay.. but I have one more doubt, if I am not applying any sort of limit to data, how does the datatable know to split my data of length 100 in 10 pages containing 10 records each? Since I am also getting a line saying "showing 1 to 10 of 100 records"...

Comment: The datatable only knows that because of the answer of the server. Eventhough you are geting the message "showing 1 to 10 of 100 records" I believe that you see more than 10 records in the page, dont you?

Comment: yes i see entire 100 records in first page itself

Comment: I would recommend you to check a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358233/jquery-datatable-server-side-processing-pagination-and-search-not-working

Comment: Something is probably wrong within your server-side php code, you should add it. It should automatically pag if done correctly.

Comment: @JeffBezos i have added it, please check the updated code

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how many records go on a page, and how many records there are.

Your SQL will end in `OFFSET 30 LIMIT 10` (for example).

First get total Records. Page will come through your URL and default to page 1 if not set.

The offset is calculated like this (example, page 3):

```
$totalPages = ceil($totalRecords / $numPerPage); // round up the way.
$offset = ($page * $numPerPage) - $numPerPage; // (3 * 10 = 30) - 10 = offset 20
```

Your SQL will therefore grab records with `OFFSET 20 LIMIT 10`

Answer (score 0):

This is what your server.php should looks like. Think you are missing some lines of code:

```
  <?php
    $table = 'employees';
    $primaryKey = 'id'; // Table's primary key

    $columns = array(
        array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
        array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 1 ),
        array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 2 ),
        array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 3 ),
        array( 'db' => 'date',     'dt' => 4 ),
         array( 'db' => 'updated',     'dt' => 5 ),
    );

    $sql_details = array(
        'user' => 'username',
        'pass' => 'password',
        'db'   => 'database',
        'host' => 'localhost'
    );

    require( 'ssp.class.php' );

    echo json_encode(
        SSP::simple( $_POST, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
    );
    ?>
```

End result: https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/

This should get you in the right direction. Think the ssp.class.php file might need added too, unsure if you have it (you can find it on github). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Jeff ... I have a follow up question.. where do I get SSP.class.php..?

Comment: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

Comment: No problem. Datatable.net forums posting help alot too as this is very specialized.